# Increment Of Variable in another way in c# win. form

Tags: c#, winforms, increment

I am **inventing an algorithm** in which i have **created a new number which is "z"** (not actually z) and i am using it with the **old numbers** (0123456789) and my new series of number looks like this (0123456789z) but the problem here is that how to write a program that gives "19 + 1" as "z" and "z + 1" as "20".

Answer (score 0):

After you edited your question, I think what you're after is this

```
public int incrementNumber(string number)
{
    var lastNumber = int.Parse(number.Last());
    return (number.Length - 1) + ((lastNumber + 1) % 10).ToString();
}
```

% 10 or Mod 10 takes the reminder of the number divided by 10. So if you pass in 9 it will increment to 10 then wrap around to 0. When you pass in 5 it will increment to 6 and stay as 6 because it's not divisible by 10.

Comment: sir that is what is said i am working on the concept of "++" but i cant use it and cant use "+ 1" too.

Comment: Hi I've updated my answer after you have updated your question. I hope this is able to help you.

Comment: i have made the question as simple as possible from my side please see if you can help me with it.

Comment: Does my new answer help? If not why not?

Comment: no sir please see the above question again their are 11 numbers now

Comment: I have had another go at it, this one follows the same logic but I adjusted it to accept a string.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be optimized but works if you allow +1 to increment.

```
 public static string NextValue(string Counting)
    {
        int nextVal;
        if(int.TryParse(Counting, out nextVal))
        {
            return (nextVal + 1).ToString();
        }
        else 
        {
            char[] numbers = Counting.ToCharArray();
            StringBuilder incremented = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char digit in numbers.Reverse())
            {
                if (digit == 'z')
                {
                   incremented.Append("0");
                }
                else if (int.TryParse(digit.ToString(), out nextVal))
                {
                    nextVal = nextVal + 1;
                    if (nextVal == 10)
                    {
                        incremented.Append("z");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        incremented.Append(nextVal.ToString());
                    }

                    incremented.Append(string.Concat(numbers.Reverse().Skip(incremented.Length)));
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Invalid character in number except for z
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            if (incremented[incremented.Length - 1] == '0')
                incremented.Append("1");
            return Reverse(incremented.ToString()); 
        }    
    }

     public static string Reverse(string s)
     {
         char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
         Array.Reverse(charArray);
         return new string(charArray);
     }
```

Comment: no sir i am working on the concept of "++" but i cant use it and cant use "+ 1" too.

Comment: @user3779606 so 0123456789z is the final number system for you? or it can be any combination?

Comment: so can we use +1 or ++ now or not since that has been removed from the question?

Comment: I have updated once again. But the algoright uses +1. Otherwise it assumes that you have 11 digits in your number systems. Check if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, though you'd have to implement additional coding for parameter checking and incrementing the second to last character if the last character reaches **0**.

This is the basic logic:

```
private const string DIGITS = "0123456789z";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(NextValue("9"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string NextValue(string value)
{
    char nextChar = '\0';
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        char lastChar = value[value.Length - 1];
        int nextCharIndex = DIGITS.IndexOf(lastChar) + 1;
        if (nextCharIndex > DIGITS.Length)
            nextChar = DIGITS[0];
        else
            nextChar = DIGITS[nextCharIndex];
    }
    return nextChar.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i have made the question as simple as possible from my side please see if you can help me with it.

Comment: This solution i posted will help you.. just add additional logic to check if its already the last in DIGITS then add z